# Angular Material Table no me muestra imagen, etiqueta img toma como string

Tags: angular, img, material

Estoy queriendo mostrar una imagen en una tabla de angular material. Es la misma imagen que sale sobre "foto 1, foto 2". Se guarda en una variable llamada imgData. El tema es que me toma la imagen como string, y me muestra la URL, no la imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo donde construyo la tabla:

```
 this.infoArr = [
    {
      Imagen: `<img src="${this.imgData}"/>`,
      Fabricante: ev.Proveedor.toString(),
      Artículo: ev.Cod_art,
      Color: ev.Color,
      Descripción: this.descripcion,
      'Cantidad Vendidos': ev.Cantidad_Vendidos,
      Costo: ev.Costo,
      'Precio Venta': ev.Precio_Venta,
      'Distribución Tarea': ev.Distrib,
    },
  this.dataSourceArticulo = new MatTableDataSource(this.infoArr);
```

HTML:

```
 <table
        mat-table
        [dataSource]="dataSourceArticulo"
        fixedLayout="true"
        *ngIf="dataSourceArticulo"
        class="mat-elevation-z8 info-Articulo-table"
      >
      
        <ng-container
          matColumnDef="{{ column }}"
          *ngFor="let column of filasArt"
        >
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-color">
            {{ column }}
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let datos" matTooltip="{{ mov }}">
            <p *ngIf="datos[column] !== ''">{{ datos[column] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="datos[column] == ''">NO DISPONIBLE</p>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="filasArt"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: filasArt"></tr>
      </table>
```

La consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que me toma la imagen como string pero no se como resolverlo, alguna ayuda?

Comment: es <img [src]="${this.imgData}/>... aunque no detallas nada en realidad de la tabla <ng-container ???...matColumnDef??...mat-cell?? <img ??....[dataSource]="dataSource"????

Comment: Ahi detalle mas, por cierto no me funcionó, sigue igual.

Answer (score 0):

Si no te es útil la respuesta por favor coméntame porque

> Para que te muestre una imagen se requiere una etiqueta **img** de la
> forma que esta tu codigo trata igual a un string que a una imagen
> Para que muestre imágenes una forma seria
> Forma A:

```
    //ts
    img1 = new Image();
      img2 = new Image();
      infoArr = [
        { id: 1, Imagen: this.img1 },
        { id: 2, Imagen: this.img2 },
    
      ]
      filasArt = ['id', 'Imagen'];
    
      constructor() {
        this.img1.src = "assets/images/imagen1.jpg";
        this.img2.src = "assets/images/imagen2.jpg"
      }
      ngOnInit() {
    
      }
    //html
    <img src="{{img1.src}}">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="infoArr" fixedLayout="true" class="mat-elevation-z8 info-Articulo-table">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Imagen">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Imagen </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img [src]="element.Imagen.src"></td>
    
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="filasArt"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: filasArt"></tr>
    </mat-table>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> > El codigo que muestras lo tomara como un string lo convertiría
> > respecto a mis datos  en :

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Imagen">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Imagen </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <{{"element.Imagen}}"></td>
```

Por eso falta la etiqueta img se podria usar  ng-template para comparar y así mostrar la imagen cuando la encuentra
Forma B:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="infoArr" fixedLayout="true" class="mat-elevation-z8 info-Articulo-table">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of filasArt" matColumnDef="{{ column }}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="column-color">
      {{ column }}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let datos">
      <div *ngIf="datos[column]!== img1 && datos[column]!==img2  else Image">
        <p *ngIf="datos[column] !== ''">{{ datos[column] }}</p>
      </div>
      <ng-template #Image>
        <img [src]="datos[column].src">
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="filasArt"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: filasArt"></tr>
</mat-table>
```

De no ser requerido por algo especial me parece lo mas indicado la forma A